# Do all 767-200s have speedbrakes that deploy automatically upon touchdown?

Tags: spoilers, boeing-757, boeing-767, airbrakes

It may just be a coincidence, but I found two videos that involve the 767-200's speedbrakes not deploying automatically upon touchdown (which should occur if they are armed).

The first [video](https://youtu.be/ihZK9HaIfGU?t=573) shows the speedbrake lever move less than an inch upon touchdown, then the pilot flying extends them all the way.

The second [video](https://youtu.be/RCPXlExOSmU?t=18) shows the speedbrakes not deploying at all for at least 5 seconds after touchdown, then they extend in incrementes until extending fully a few seconds after that.

Does the 767-200 have some sort of "quirk" when it comes to its speedbrakes deploying, do some 767s not have an "armed" function, or are these just coincidences where they failed to automatically deploy?

**P.S.** I also have this [footage](https://youtu.be/ygMTncjJtKg?t=112) of the 757's first flight where the speedbrakes clearly do not deploy automatically, either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All B757 and B767 aircraft have speedbrakes that can be deployed automatically. But you need to manually arm them first. You also need weight on wheels(truck tilt) and both thrust levers at idle, before they automatically deploy. Moving the reverse levers to the idle reverse detent will also raise the speedbrakes, even if they are not armed.

On some landings they will start to deploy and then stop if there is not enough weight on wheels, due to a little bounce or float. The flying pilot will then usually manually deploy them.

In your first video, it looks like the speedbrake was not armed. Your second video looks pretty normal, but the landing was so smooth, it’s hard to tell when the wheels were on the ground. It may have been a manual deployment, or deployment with the thrust reversers. The third B757 video looks like late deployment, so it may have been manual as well.

Comment: Thanks, @Mike Sowsun. But the speedbrakes only deploy after 4 seconds once even the nose gear is on the ground in the third (757) video. Did they fail to deploy or were they probably simply not armed?

Comment: Thanks guys, meant to say “idle reverse detent”, so I edited my answer. On the 757 video, it does look like a late deployment, so I edited that part too.

Comment: Yup, thanks for being a proofreader. :)

Comment: Is this still true for the small number of 767s that were produced with manual (three-person) cockpits?